# OverrideLibrary min version using an Android Library

Tags: android, android-manifest

I've just followed this [Android Documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library#AddDependency) to add my AAR as a module but I'm getting this error.

```
Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 18 cannot be smaller than version 19 declared in library [:miSDK] /mypath/build/.transforms/2f9346edc5a772d83c981ee402c3411f/mylib/AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 18
    
Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 18,
        or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 19,
        or use tools:overrideLibrary="com.my.lib" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)
```

So my problem is that I don't know where should I place this override since the module that contains my library hasn't a Manifest.

Answer (score 0):

I finally manage to solve it like this:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.my.app">
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="18"
        tools:overrideLibrary="com.my.lib" />
    ...
</manifest>
```